# Recursive anonymus function in kotlin

Tags: recursion, kotlin, anonymous-function

Im making this anonymus function, and i need it to call *itself*. Is there any way to do it? I tried the code below, which didnt work...

```
val example:Char = fun () : Char { 
    //Some code
    if(condition) {
        return this();
    } 
}
```

What should i replace 'this()' with?
Im pretty new to kotlin, so it would be really helpful with a response

Answer (score 2):

You can't name anonymous functions (either with this syntax, or as a lambda) in Kotlin, and therefore you can't make them recursive either, because you have know way to reference themselves.

If you need recursion, you'll have to create a regular function, and call that:

```
fun helper() : Char {
     if (condition) {
        return helper();
    }
    ...
}

val example = helper()
```

The good news is that you can basically create a regular, named function in [any scope](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#function-scope). They can be top level outside classes, class members, or just local functions nested within other functions. Wherever you can write down `val example = ...`, you can also create a function.

Answer (score 2):

Calling an anonymous function sound complicated as there is no name to call it with :)
As I'm learning Kotlin myself at the moment, I tried something and came up with this, hope it helps:

```
import kotlin.test.Test
import kotlin.test.assertEquals

class StackOverflow51233329 {

    @Test
    fun test() {
        var letter = 'A'

        lateinit var example: () -> Char

        example = {
            letter++   
            if (letter >= 'C') letter else example()
        }

        assertEquals('C', example())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using `lateinit`, you could use the [Y combinator](https://mvanier.livejournal.com/2897.html), which can be used to enable recursion when recursion is impossible directly. Declare this globally:

```kotlin
class RecursiveFunc<T, R>(val f: (RecursiveFunc<T, R>) -> (T) -> R)

fun <T, R> y(f: ((T) -> R) -> (T) -> R): (T) -> R {
    val rec = RecursiveFunc<T, R> { r -> f { r.f(r)(it) } }
    return rec.f(rec)
}
```

This code was taken from [Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Y_combinator#Kotlin). You use it like this:

```
val fac = y { f: ((Int) -> Int) ->
    { n: Int ->
        if (n <= 1) 1 else n * f(n - 1)
    }
}
println(fac(10))
```

`f` is the recursive function here, with a signature of `(Int) -> Int`. The rest of the function is pretty much the same as usual, but in lambda form. You can even use the usual function syntax if that's more familiar:

```
val fac = y { f: (Int) -> Int ->
    fun(n: Int): Int {
        return if (n <= 1) 1 else n * f(n - 1)
    }
}
```